# Kentico - Couldn't get DocumentPageTemplateID with node inherit temlate from parent

Tags: macros, kentico

I'm using macro to get DocumentPageTemplateID  inside master page, it work fine in parent template that using a page template directly, but i always got zero with children page that inheriting template from parent.

Is there a way to get inherited value (more than 1 level)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check to see if the document is inheriting the template from the parent, then go up to the parent by using `{%CurrentDocument.Parent.DocumentPageTemplateID%}` or up 2 levels `{%CurrentDocument.Parent.Parent.DocumentPageTemplateID%}`